# Excel SUMIF function sums multiple and/or wrong column.

Tags: excel-formula, sumifs

I'm having an issue getting accurate data from the SUMIF function. This appears to be caused by the SKU and Product name being identical however I don't understand why the selected range would be ignored.

SUMIF(G:K,A2,K:K) - Cell D2 is calling for the sum of K yet returning the sum result of K2:M2. All other results in D are correct.

SUMIF(G:K,A2,I:I) - If I change the formula in D to SUM I:I (text not a numeric field) the function returns the sum of K:K

Example file http://tempsend.com/013C2B6378

Answer (score 1):

According to the documentation [here](https://support.office.com/en-au/article/SUMIF-function-5fd078db-e5f8-4726-b08f-74fd0064e7fe?ui=en-US&rs=en-AU&ad=AU) the range to be summed starts at the top left of the sum range (K:K in your first example) but its size is given by the size of the criteria range (G:K in your example). So I think that's why you're getting extra columns summed in your result.

If you have multiple criteria involving different columns, you should be able to use [SUMIFS](https://support.office.com/en-in/article/SUMIFS-function-9dd6179e-cced-41dd-ac38-08fdf5b929e5).

Answer (score 0):

So let's say your data sit in 8 rows (including the headings).

then you simply need to change your formula to say, look for **B2** in column **G** ***OR*** in **I**, if true, then sum the values in **K**. Right?

put this formula in **B2** and press <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>enter</kbd> to calculate the formula.

```
=SUM(IF(($G$2:$G$8=B2)+($I$2:$I$8=B2),1,0)*$K$2:$K$8)
```

then drag and fill down until the last cell.

obviously you need to adjust the ranges in the formula to adapt to your own data.

tell me if you get to the answer via this.